# Can I pipe/redirect a console application through netcat so it can be used remotely?

Tags: linux, networking, console, netcat

Is it possible to 'pipe' an instance of a console application through netcat, so netcat is listening for a new connection and redirects the `stdin` and `stdout` over the network connection.

Comment: yeah but it might have to be a  one liner, which is fine, pipes are so. I don't know whether you can tell nc and pipe to an already running instance by pid. you can nc to an ip and pipe it to an nc that is listening and pipe that to an nc that is listening etc and pipe that to nc to an ip.

Comment: I changed the title because what you mention sounds more like I/O *redirection* rather than the use of a pipe (which only deals with moving the *output* of one process to the *input* of another).

Comment: @Breakthrough how does that differ from pipes? as  he's talking about IO redirection and not talking about files, then how does it differ from piping?

Comment: @barlop I/O redirection (`<` or `>`) is significantly different from piping (`|`), although you can sometimes achieve an equivalent operation with a mix of both.  Again though, with I/O redirection, you can change the location of *both* streams; piping just redirects the standard output of one process to the standard input of another.

Comment: @Breakthrough see what I asked you though. > and < is of course different from piping because < and > use files. But he's not talking of files.  I asked you "how does that[IO redirection] differ from pipes? as he's talking about IO redirection and not talking about files, then how does it differ from piping? "

Comment: @barlop see Scott's answer below.  Piping only deals with the standard output of the spawned process, and not the standard input.  You need to somehow *redirect* it from another asynchronous process (like sockets).  However, I do see what you meant now.  So yes, I/O redirection even without files is not equivalent to piping (as per the semantics of what a pipe does).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9250/discussion-between-barlop-and-breakthrough)

Comment: @barlop added some notes to the discussion.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, as documented in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat#Making_any_process_a_server) and `netcat` documentation, there is a `-e` option that causes it to spawn (**e**xecute) a program upon receipt of a connection, attaching the socket to stdin, stdout, and stderr of the process.  Example usage:

> `nc -l -p`*port_number*`-e`*program_name*

Examples commonly show `/bin/sh` or `bash` being used as the *program_name*.  Use of this option is discouraged because it basically opens an anonymous, passwordless access portal into your machine.  Of course, this is mitigated by using a program with less power than the shell (one that doesn’t have the ability to escape to a shell), minimizing your use of it, and keeping it a secret.  Nonetheless, the original developers of `netcat` felt strongly enough that this option was a bad idea that they disabled it by default, and conditioned it under the “GAPING_SECURITY_HOLE” compilation option.  This is mentioned briefly in this [NetCat Tutorial](http://www.packetsource.com/article/security-tools/40061/netcat-tutorial) and other `netcat` documentation.

A Google search led me to discussions of this issue on other Stack Exchange sites: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8161475/1672723) and [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/q/237584).  Multiple contributors offered the following technique to do the same thing without using the `-e` option (i.e., in a version of `netcat` that has the `-e` option disabled):

> On the server:
>   `mkfifo`*pipe_name*
>   `nc -l -p`*port_number*`<`*pipe_name*  `|` *program_name*`>`*pipe_name*
>
> On the client:
>   `nc` *server_machine_name* *port_number*

A couple of notes:

- On some versions of `netcat`, `-l` implies `-p`, so you should say just `-l` and then the port number.
- You might want to wrap your solution in a `while true` loop.